# How to route messges which will cause DestinationResolutionException to a customized error channel in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In my case, the application receives mqtt messages and routes them to a certain channel based on the type value in the messages. Such, I defined a `IntegrationFlow` to route the messages as follows:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mqttInbound() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(inbound())
            .transform(new PojoTransformer())
            .<Data, String>route(Data::getType,
                    m -> m.prefix("Channel."))
            .get();
}
```

And also, I defined some other `IntegrationFlow`s to handle the messages in these channels, e.g.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow normalProcess() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("Channel.1")
            .handle("normalHandler", "handle")
            .channel("mqttOutboundChannel")
            .get();
}
```

The problem is if there are no defined mappings (e.g. type is "4"), an exception will occur which says something like `org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'Channel.4' in the BeanFactory`. My question is how can I route all these unmapped messages to a certain error channel and then I can do something exception handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `resolutionRequired` to false and add a default output channel.

```
        .<Data, String>route(Data::getType,
                m -> m.prefix("Channel.")
                      .resolutionRequired(false)
                      .defaultOutputChannel("noRouteChannel"))
```